# 2,5m cable too long for LCD connected to Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, communication

So i got that 2,5m cable wired with the LCD and the arduino, but i keep getting those weird characters showing up on the LCD. Clearly there is a signal loss between the components but there has to be a solution to the problem. Perhaps by connecting capacitors/resistors to the wires will help? Is there any solution other than not using this long cable?

Comment: Try shielding the cable. Wrap it in tin-foil or something.

Comment: 2.5m of what cable? What interface are you using for the LCD?

Answer (score 1):

If the interface you're using is I2C(only two cables from arduino to lcd, vice versa)you have a problem,you need to pull up the sda-scl channel with appropriate resistors, you could (maybe) boost the I2C signal using ti-p82b715 bus extender, I just assume you use I2C (2,5m length?), what interface do you use? SPI? I2C?

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming this is I2C or SPI, because a Serial cable of 2.5 m should still work.

You can slow both I2C and SPI down.

---

In the case of [SPI](http://www.gammon.com.au/spi) you can call something like this:

```
SPI.setClockDivider(divider);
```

Where "divider" is one of:

- SPI_CLOCK_DIV2
- SPI_CLOCK_DIV4
- SPI_CLOCK_DIV8
- SPI_CLOCK_DIV16
- SPI_CLOCK_DIV32
- SPI_CLOCK_DIV64
- SPI_CLOCK_DIV128

The default is SPI_CLOCK_DIV4, so try a larger divider.

---

In the case of [I2C](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c) you can change the clock speed and the prescaler. The default frequency is 100 kHz, but you could make it slower.

```
TWBR   prescaler   Frequency

  12       1       400   kHz  (the maximum supported frequency)
  32       1       200   kHz
  72       1       100   kHz  (the default)
 152       1        50   kHz
  78       4        25   kHz
 158       4        12.5 kHz
```

For example, to run at half the frequency (50 kHz) use:

```
  Wire.begin ();
  TWBR = 152;
```

To run at 25 kHz you also need to change the prescaler, eg.

```
  Wire.begin ();
  TWBR = 78;  
  TWSR |= bit (TWPS0);
```

In the case of I2C make sure you have pull-up resistors on SDA and SCL in order to get a clean signal. 4.7 k is a reasonable value to try (for both of them) with the other ends connected to +5 V.

Comment: Sorry. I probably should have mentioned hat my LCD is connected to an arduino expander - a mcp23017 to be specific - which is connected to the arduino. Therefore I guess that I use I2c?

Comment: Yes, the MCP23017 is I2C. The MCP23S17 is SPI. You should have four wires in that case: +5V, Gnd, SDA, SCL. Make sure you have the 4.7 k pull-up resistors on SDA and SCL (at the Arduino end). Also try dropping the I2C frequency as shown above.